# Does anyone have data or shapefiles for tidal flats, mangrove distribution, or salt marshes?

Tags: data

I am looking to map out the salt marshes, mangroves, and tidal flats of the world, but I am having difficulty finding data for this. Does anyone have any such data? This is for a research project at my university.

Answer (score 6):

File Geodatabase of Mangroves here

http://www.iucnredlist.org/technical-documents/spatial-data#mangroves

Mangroves

The ranges are available as a single data set (File Geodatabase) for most plant species that considered to form part of the mangrove ecosystem.

**Mangroves (zip file, 97.8 MB)**

See [metadata document](http://i.iucnredlist.org/spatial-data/2010.4/GISData/RLSpatial_metadata_Oct2010.pdf) for further information.

Comment: This is more of a potential species database as opposed to an actual location database. You should use Giri for 2000 data (http://www.marineclimatechange.com/marineclimatechange/bluecarbon_2_files/Girietal2011.pdf) or this for 2012.

Answer (score 3):

I believe those are also available in the [National Wetland invnetory](http://www.fws.gov/wetlands/Data/State-Downloads.html).
Managed by U.S Fish and Wildlife.
Perhaps not broken out quite like you mentioned.

This legend shows [Vegetated and non-vegetated brackish and saltwater marsh, shrubs, beach, bar, shoal or flat](http://www.fws.gov/wetlands/Data/Mapper-Wetlands-Legend.html) all together.

And this [code chart](http://www.fws.gov/wetlands/Documents/Wetlands-and-Deepwater-Habitats-Classification-chart.pdf) shows how to break out class-subclass and modifiers.

[image: From the FWS website]
And even an area to [contribute data](http://www.fws.gov/wetlands/Data/Contributed-Data.html).

Answer (score 1):

Koordinates.com are usually great with these things.

For example, here's one for the whole of New Zealand.

http://koordinates.com/maps/department-conservation/#/layer/148-nz-mangroves/

Answer (score 1):

This database does it for mangrove globally for 2012 inclining percentage mangrove cover at the 30 m pixel level.

This is the [URL](http://arxiv.org/abs/1412.0722) to the paper and below is the data link.

http://faculty.salisbury.edu/~sehamilton/mangroves/

and this [one](http://data.unep-wcmc.org/datasets/4) has year 2000 presence and absence globally.

The IUCN Redlist link above is not actually a true mangrove location but a potential species region DB.